# mongodb updateMany query storing string instead of reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

**this is my product collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("640de93a469aa38cb4ceec7e"),
    "product_title" : "Colorful Pattern Shirt",
    "product_sku" : "shirt003",
    "product_color" : "white",
    "product_size" : "32",
    "product_brand" : "nike",
    "product_description" : "cotton material good shirt",
    "product_price" : NumberInt(3000),
    "product_warranty" : "1 Year AL Jazeera Brand Warranty",
    "product_return" : "30 Day Return Policy",
    "product_quantity" : "10",
    "product_category" : "Womens",
    "delivery[]" : [
        "Cash On Delivery",
        "Credit Card",
        "Debit Card",
        "UPI",
        "Paypal"
    ],
    "offerPrice" : 888.0,
    "isActive" : true,
    "offerEndDate" : "2023-03-10"
}
```

*and it has a field called offerPrice , the bug is while setting the offerPrice to the product_price *

*this is the update query **

```
const moment = require('moment')
      // Calculate the date when the offer ends
      const offerEndDate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').toDate()
      // Convert offerEndDate to a string in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
      const isoOfferEndDate = moment(offerEndDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
const result = await db.get().collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).updateMany(
  {
    offerEndDate: { $lt: isoOfferEndDate }
  }
  {
    $unset: { offerEndDate: 1 },
    $set: {
      offerPrice: "$product_price"
    }
  }
)
```

*but in after performing this query. the offer Price stored like this in database
*
   `"offerPrice" : "$product_price",`

- i have also tried the `$$ROOT.product_price`
- 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to a field in a document with `$fieldName` is an aggregation operation, and is not valid in a regular update.

You can use that type of operation with the aggregation form of update, passing an array of aggregation stages instead of an update document:

```
.updateMany(
  {
    offerEndDate: { $lt: isoOfferEndDate }
  },
  [
   {$unset: "offerEndDate" },
   {$set: {offerPrice: "$product_price"}}
  ]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7LLYLKa0BgY)